# How can I make my code faster?

Tags: performance, matlab

I write this code for solving problem 4- project euler, but it takes too long for giving me the answer.

Is there any trick to make it faster?

```
function S=Problem4(n)
tic
Interval=10^(n-1):10^(n)-1;
[Product1,Product2]=meshgrid(Interval);
Func=@(X,Y) X*Y;
Temp=cell2mat(arrayfun(Func,Product1,Product2,'UniformOutput',false));
Palindrome=@(X) all(num2str(X)==fliplr(num2str(X)));
Temp2=unique(Temp(:));
S=max(Temp2(arrayfun(Palindrome,Temp2)));
toc
end
```

and it takes about 39 secs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please describe the problem and also explain the logic behind your code

Comment: And make sure to check and present the output of [profile](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html)

Comment: Have you got a chance to try out the various approaches posted on this page to solve your problem? We would be eager to know how they performed!

Answer (score 2):

From [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4):

> **Largest palindrome product**
> Problem 4
>
> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Instead of analyzing your code, I'll give you another way of doing it, which you might find useful. It makes use of vectorization, avoiding `arrayfun` and anonymous functions, which may be slow:

```
[n1, n2] = ndgrid(100:999); %// all combinations of 3-digit numbers
pr = n1(:).*n2(:); %// product of each combination
de = dec2base(pr, 10); %// decimal expression of those products
sm = pr<1e5; %// these have 5 figures: initial digit "0" should be disregarded
pa = false(1,numel(pr)); %// this will indicate if each product is palindromic or not
pa(sm) = all(de(sm,2:end) == fliplr(de(sm,2:end)), 2); %// 5-figure palindromic
pa(~sm) = all(de(~sm,:) == fliplr(de(~sm,:)), 2); %// 6-figure palindromic
result = max(pr(pa)); %// find maximum among all products indicated by pa
```

You can save almost half the time by avoiding duplicate products, as follows. The three new lines are marked:

```
[n1, n2] = ndgrid(100:999); %// all combinations of 3-digit numbers
un = n1(:)<=n2(:); %// NEW
n1 = n1(un); %//       NEW
n2 = n2(un); %//       NEW
pr = n1(:).*n2(:); %// product of each combination
de = dec2base(pr, 10); %// decimal expression of those products
sm = pr<1e5; %// these have 5 figures: initial digit "0" should be disregarded
pa = false(1,numel(pr)); %// this will indicate if each product is palindromic or not
pa(sm) = all(de(sm,2:end) == fliplr(de(sm,2:end)), 2); %// 5-figure palindromic
pa(~sm) = all(de(~sm,:) == fliplr(de(~sm,:)), 2); %// 6-figure palindromic
result = max(pr(pa)); %// find maximum among all products indicated by pa
```

Comment: Guess there are similarities in terms of using `dec2base` and `all` between our solutions, but I thought I could post an iterative based approach and also avoid `ndgrid/meshgrid` with `bsxfun` which must be more efficient. Hope this is all okay!

Comment: @Divakar Of course! I should have thought of `bsxfun`

Answer (score 2):

Only a partial answer here, but a big performance hit is often caused by using strings to handle numbers.

And here you have a function that even does it twice in one line!

First try to get rid of one by saving the intermediate result in a variable. If that saves a significant amount of time it is probably worth removing the other one as well.

---

Here is my own approach from a few years back. It is not that great, but perhaps it can inspire you.

Note that it does use `num2str`, but only once and on all relevant numbers at once. In your code you use `arrayfun` which basically uses a loop internally, and probably results in many calls to `num2str`.

```
clear
field = (100:999)'*(100:999);
field = field(:);
fieldstr = num2str(field);
idx = fieldstr(:,1) == fieldstr(:,end);
idx2 = fieldstr(:,2) == fieldstr(:,end-1);
idx3 = fieldstr(:,3) == fieldstr(:,end-2);
list = fieldstr(idx & idx2 & idx3,:);
listnum = str2num(list);
max(listnum)
```

Comment: Takes about 26.2 seconds. If you find a trick to remove the conversions to and from strings (as in the now deleted answer by @Luis) it reduces to about 0.2 seconds.

Comment: There was a mistake. I've corrected it now. +1 for your answer BTW

Comment: Actually I use strings too, but `dec2base` seems to be faster

Answer (score 1):

### Some Discussion and Solution Code

Since you are looking for the `maximum` palindrome, after you have collected possible *product numbers* with that `Interval`, for every possible `number of digits` for `all the numbers` you can iteratively look for the maximum possible number. Thus, with `n = 3`, you would have from `10000` to `998001` as the products. So, you can look for the maximum palindrome number within the `6 digit` numbers first, then go for `5 digits` ones and so on. The benefit with such an iterative approach would be that you can **`get out`** of the function as soon as you have the `max` number. Here's the code to fulfil the promises laid in the discussion -

```
function S = problem4_try1(n)

Interval=10^(n-1):10^(n)-1; %// Define interval definition here

prods = bsxfun(@times,Interval,Interval'); %//'# Or Use: Interval'*Interval
allnums = prods(:);

numd = ceil(log10(allnums));        %// number of digits
dig = sort(unique(numd),'descend'); %// unique digits starting from highest one

for iter = 1:numel(dig)
    numd_iter = dig(iter);
    numd_iter_halflen = floor(numd_iter/2);
    
    all_crit = allnums(numd==numd_iter); %//all numbers in current iteration
    all_crit_dg = dec2base(all_crit,10)-'0'; %// separate digits for a 2D array

    all_curit_digits_pal = all_crit(all(all_crit_dg(:,1:numd_iter_halflen) == ...
        all_crit_dg(:,end:-1:end-numd_iter_halflen+1) ,2)); %// palindrome matches
    
    %// Find the max of palindrom matches and get out
    if ~isempty(all_curit_digits_pal)
        S = max(all_curit_digits_pal);
        return;                         %//  *** Get Outta Here!!
    end
end
```

**Few things about the code itself**

1. `bsxfun(@times,Interval,Interval')` efficiently gets us the product values, which you have in `Temp` and as such this must be pretty efficient, as don't have to deal with the intermediate `Product1` and `Product2`.
2. Because of the iterative nature, it must be efficient enough for higher `n`'s, given the system can handle the pre-processing part of the calculation of the products at the start.

Answer (score -4):

I encourage you to see this link ([improving matlab performance](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/MATLAB/programming/performance.html)), also, i recommend using a "cache/memory" funcion, when you have iterations of calculations you can store the parameters and answers so next time you have the same parameters you just return the stored answer skipping some calculations in the process.

Hope it helps someway, tell me if you have more doubts.

Comment: Nice link in general, but it does not seem to cover the main problem in his code.

Comment: Storing or caching the calculations isn't enough to fully solve the problem the OP is experiencing.